# Is it possible the subscribe any page's Real Time Updates?

Tags: c#, facebook

I wan't to subscribe any page's real time updates.

Is it possible? If is not i'm not sure which page can i allowed to subscribe. Can i subscribe following page's real time updates?

https://www.facebook.com/platform

Comment: You say this is a C# question, What are the components, libraires, code being used here? What have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/realtime/:

> Types of Updates
>
> It is possible to subscribe to the following types of updates: […]
>
> - Page - Get notifications when **pages that have installed your app as a Tab** change some of their public properties

Now what is still unclear after reading that …?

Comment: It's unclear. Because the page i don't know how to set pages to subscribe?

I mean, any page. I want to specify to page i wan't to subscribe. Example:

realtime.facebook.com/pageids=12341435,1234535435345

Comment: You don't get updates for just any page, only those that have your app installed as a page tab.

Comment: Thanks, but that isn't suitable for making rival analysis.

Comment: Well perhaps you’re not meant to be able to do that this easily …

Comment: Twitter API gives us that. Its so easy :). Of course i expect to facebook gives as well. Thanks again.

https://dev.twitter.com/docs/streaming-apis